Prevent antimeridian geometry artifacts with H3 and Leaflet
I am drawing hex bins via h3geo on a Leaflet map and am being bitten in the behind by the antimeridian artifacts using a pretty standard approach
const map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 2);
const mapSource = 'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';

L.tileLayer(mapSource, {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '…'
    }).addTo(map);

const bins = {
    "80b9fffffffffff":2725,
    "80c9fffffffffff":1389,
    "80bffffffffffff":13789,
    "8009fffffffffff":3646
    …
};

const grid = [];
for (const [ h3id, num ] of Object.entries(bins)) {
    grid.push({
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { h3id, num },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [h3.cellToBoundary(h3id, true)]
        }
    })
}

L.geoJSON(grid, {
    style: getStyle(…)
}).addTo(map);


How can I draw this correctly without those wrapping lines?

Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Added code is not enough to reproduce the image above. Please add more relevant code.

it is really a pretty basic leaflet map… there is no additional code other than setting it up and drawing the bins. I've added that basic bit above. A snippet of the data is shown in bins{}

Provided bins do not cross antimeridian. Please provide some the do.

I'm surprised there aren't more questions with these tags (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet+antimeridian), but there's nothing peculiar to H3 here (it's inteference in the core problem), so I have edited the title.

@punkish your solution is only "specific to H3" in that you transform from H3 to GeoJSON by using h3.cellToBoundary. The problem would be exhibited with any feature that crosses the antimeridian, not just H3 cells represented in GeoJSON. So your solution is actually more generally useful.

There are actually a few other questions tagged with antimeridian. I hope this thread is useful to as many people as possible, but specifically, for someone looking to make the H3 bins, this will be immediately and completely helpful and usable. Just adding the word "H3" in the title makes specific for those working with H3 and yet, generic for anyone facing the same problem with Leaflet in general

for anyone facing the same problem, here is the code that fixes the antimeridian artifacts
// assuming an array of h3 bins
const bins = [
    "80b9fffffffffff",
    "80c9fffffffffff",
    "80bffffffffffff",
    "8009fffffffffff",
    …
];

// construct a grid
const features = bins.map(h3id => {

    // reverse lat,lng to lng,lat
    const coordinates = h3.cellToBoundary(h3id, true).map(c => [c[1], c[0]]);
    return {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": …,
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [ coordinates ]
        }
    }
});
const grid = { "type": "FeatureCollection", features };
fixTransmeridian(grid);

function fixTransmeridian(feature) {
    const {type} = feature;

    if (type === 'FeatureCollection') {
        feature.features.map(fixTransmeridian);
        return;
    }

    const {type: geometryType, coordinates} = feature.geometry;
    switch (geometryType) {
        case 'LineString':
            fixTransmeridianLoop(coordinates);
            return;

        case 'Polygon':
            fixTransmeridianPolygon(coordinates);
            return;

        case 'MultiPolygon':
            coordinates.forEach(polygon => fixTransmeridianPolygon(polygon));
            return;

        default:
            throw new Error(`Unknown geometry type: ${geometryType}`);
    }
}

function fixTransmeridianCoord(coord) {
    const lng = coord[0];
    coord[0] = lng < 0 
        ? lng + 360 
        : lng;
}

function fixTransmeridianLoop(loop) {
    let isTransmeridian = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < loop.length; i++) {

        // check for arcs > 180 degrees longitude, flagging as transmeridian
        if (Math.abs(loop[0][0] - loop[(i + 1) % loop.length][0]) > 180) {
            isTransmeridian = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isTransmeridian) {
        loop.forEach(coord => fixTransmeridianCoord(coord));
    }
}

function fixTransmeridianPolygon(polygon) {
    polygon.forEach(loop => fixTransmeridianLoop(loop));
}

